# Is there a way to group services in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, angular-services

I have a sparse project, through it's many components a service is called to fetch data from an API server. This service handles from login to multiple other functions that have no direct influence of one another. Yet, separating them would make a troublesome mess in the constructors having to import multiple services. For example, this:

```js
@Component()
class ComponentExemple {
     constructor(private back: BackendService) {}
}
```

Would become more like this

```js
@Component()
class ComponentExemple {
     constructor(
     private back: BackendService0,
     private back: BackendService1,
     private back: BackendService2,
     private back: BackendService3,
     ...
     ) {}
}
```

**What I'm asking is: Is there is a way to group multiple services into one ?** (just as a class can extend another parent class, but in this context it would require the extension of multiple other parent classes). Like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class BackendService extends DataService1, DataService2, ... { }
```

Even if that is not possible (which I guess is not easily possible), is there some guideline to make the constructor parameters less cluttered ?

I need to modularize this backend service so that it's easier to maintain the code, and so other contribuitors.

Comment: Of course that is possible (unless I’m misunderstanding you). You can have a single service class and add many service methods in there. Only one thing needed in your constructor..

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you said that could be done.

Comment: I don't understand this, why would a component be dependent on all these services, I think the scope of your component is bigger than it has to be, I strongly suggest reading [this](https://blog.bitsrc.io/atomic-design-and-ui-components-theory-to-practice-f200db337c24)

Comment: Yeah, this is the state after applying an atomic model. Even though all the components and modules are really granular, atomizing the service for the backend (which has many endpoints and functions to execute) would result in almost 37 services for each category, and an average of 6 to 7 imports per component. What I need is a way to separate the file for easy maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attempt using mixins to have some kind of multiple extends, but I suggest using composition instead:

```js
@Injectable()
export class BackendService {
  constructor(
    public data1: DataService1,
    public data2: DataService2,
    public data3: DataService3,
    public data4: DataService4
  ) {}
}

@Component()
class ComponentExemple {
  constructor(
    private back: BackendService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.back.data1.getStuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, as this does make enforces a use of explicit syntax, and permits a kind of namespace. The problem would be when these services would need to share some resource, like an object or another single instance.

Comment: From this answer I ask now: if when I declare the other services in the 'main' services they would instantiate again if the main is recreated ?

Comment: It depends on how the service are provided, if you provide them all in your root module (AppModule), you will have a single instance of each services.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your single service as implementation for many other services.

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        { provide: DataService1, useClass: BackendService},
        { provide: DataService2, useClass: BackendService},
        ...
    ]
}

@Injectable()
export class BackendService implements DataService1, DataService2, ... { }
```

Note how I used `implements` instead of `extends`.
So, your DataServices behave as interfaces. BackendService won't inherit any methods, you need to write all methods like when you write a Facade.

Then you can start gradually refactoring, implementing DataService1 and so on.

Comment: So I would still need to implement all the methods on BackendService ? Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of modularizing the backend service ?

Comment: My answer would only help you if you want to take an iterative (gradual) approach.
First you declare your classes as abstract, and declare BackendService implementing them.
As you start to modularize, your BackendService can just require DataSource1, and forward the calls to it. Then DataSource2, and so on.
In the end BackendService will be just a Facade forwarding all the calls to the real services.